# how can change default text editor in mingw32

Tags: cygwin, sublime-text-2

I would like to change or add the ability to open files when working with mingw32 with a different text editor ( in my case sublime text 2 ) I have been googling around  but I'm not sure i understand how to do this.

I would like to be able to do the following from the command line:

```
$ st textfile.text -- where st is a command to use st2 to open the textfile.
```

you can already do this with vim

I'd appreciate any pointers.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `EDITOR` enviroment variable. Set it for a single shell instance with:

```
export EDITOR=<path to your editor>
```

Or add that to `.bashrc` to set it automatically for all new shell instances.

Comment: does mingw32 have a .bashrc file? I have been unable to find it

Answer (score 1):

If the sublime text 2 application is named st.exe, add the directory where it is to PATH.
Doing it only for mingw32 should be possible with adding it in your .bashrc like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<msyspath-to-st-directory>
```

But you could aswell add it to Environment variables in Windows to make it work in cmd.exe aswell.

Comment: does mingw32  have a .bashrc file? I have been unable to find it.

Comment: not by default (probably), but you can create one.. if so it should be wherever your HOME directory is. But I suggest you change PATH in Windows Environment variables instead.